# Apache AGE- How to read a CSV File

Tags: postgresql, graph-databases, apache-age

I am using apache age and I have a CSV file with a bunch of data in it. I want to populate my graph using the information in the csv file, so can anyone help me with this, and also tell me if I have to preprocess my CSV file so that it is readable by the function which is going to be called by apache age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can load data from CSV files into Postrgres using Apache AGE.  The docs detail the steps necessary here:  https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/agload.html

It is likely that you will need to preprocess your files so that the columns and headings are in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Function **load_labels_from_file** is used to load vertices from the CSV files. Sample format is showing below:

```
load_labels_from_file('<graph name>', '<label name>','<file path>')
```

As well as if we want to exclude the id field, then we need to add fourth parameter as false which such as:
*** Use this when there is no id field in the file***

```
load_labels_from_file('<graph name>', '<label name>','<file path>',false)
```

Again, Function **load_edges_from_file** can be used to load properties from the CSV file. Please see the file structure in the following.

Note: make sure that ids in the edge file are identical to ones that are in vertices files.

```
load_edges_from_file('<graph name>','<label name>','<file path>');
```

You can check this tutorial from official page([age](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/agload.html)).

Answer (score 0):

You can populate a graph using the information in the CSV file. According to the documentation, there are two steps for the loading of graph:

1. loading of vertices and
2. loading of edges

'load_labels_from_file' is used to load vertices from the CSV files and 'load_edges_from_file' can be used to load properties from the CSV files.

You can find detailed information about it in this documentation: https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/agload.html